# How to stick to bottom on scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to achieve a similar I saw [here](https://codepen.io/brumgb/pen/GRJBeNP)

but the content of each section should also be scroll-able i.e. they should only stick when the bottom of the section has been reached.

for example when the content is `200vh` like this:

```css
section {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 200vh;
}

section img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%
}


section:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: rgb(225, 204, 200);
}

section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: rgb(240, 216, 163);
}

section:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: rgb(192, 211, 217);
}
```

```html
<section>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/128/800/300" alt="">
</section>

<section>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/48/800/300"alt="">
</section>

<section>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/42/800/300" alt="">
</section>
```

as you can see 1 & 2 sections stick to the top & we can't scroll through it's photo
but the last section works perfectly.

so how do I achieve this effect? Ideally with pure css but I'm open to a javascript solution

Comment: not sure about the issue here, are you trying to get rid of the extra bit of scrolling between sections?

Comment: @Dhia I'm trying to scroll the entire height of the section and then stick to the end. From the example, I want the first and second section's to follow the 3rd sections behaviour

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution! Using a one liner in javascript to set the `top`

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".item").forEach((el)=>{ el.style.top=(document.documentElement.clientHeight - el.offsetHeight)+"px" });
```

```css
section{
  position:sticky;
  width:100%;
  height:200vh;
}

img{
  object-fit:cover;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="item">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/128/800">
</section>

<section class="item">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/48/800">
</section>

<section class="item">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/42/800">
</section>
```

Though I'm not sure if this will work if the window is resized
but you can always use `onresize` to cover that case

I'm still open to a pure css solution if there is one?

Answer (score -1):

I has able to solve this by wrapping the sections into a main div section and few extra lines of css however to achieve the exact same style as the example you gave the sections have to be 100vh. With 200vh this solution still works but you'll have to do some extra scrolling to reach the next slide. I have prepared a codejs [fiddle here](https://codejs.com/qodejs?file=524256) with the working code, simply change 100vh to 200vh to see if it works for you.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".item").forEach((el)=>{ el.style.top=(document.documentElement.clientHeight - el.offsetHeight)+"px" });
```

```css
.mainSection {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

section {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section img {
  /*object-fit:cover;*/
  width: 70%;
  height: 100% overflow: scroll;
}


section:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: rgb(225, 204, 200);
}

section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: rgb(240, 216, 163);
}

section:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: rgb(192, 211, 217);
}
```

```html
<div class="mainSection">
  <section class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/128/800/300" alt="">
  </section>

  <section class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/48/800/300" alt="">
  </section>

  <section class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/42/800/300" alt="">
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I added a fourth image so your last image was doing the same as the middle and beggining one. Yoou just have to adjust the spacing so that you can see them being scrolled through. Take off position sticky as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        /* {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        body,html {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            display:flex;
            align-items:center;
            justify-content:center;
        }
*/
        section {
  top: 0;
  height: 200vh;
}

section img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin-bottom:60px;
}


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/128/800/300" alt="">
    </section>
    
    <section>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/48/800/300"alt="">
    </section>
    
    <section>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/42/800/300" alt="">
    </section>

    <section>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/128/800/300" alt="">
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```